# German living in Switzerland working remotely for German company

Tags: switzerland, german-citizens

Both me and my girlfriend are German. I might have to move to Zurich (Switzerland) to work there for a Swiss company. Unfortunately, my girlfriend's job is specific to Germany (she's a tax advisor) so she has to keep working for a German company. She could do so remotely.

I should have no problem getting a visa because I'll be working for a Swiss company. But what about my girlfriend?

Given the income differences between Germany and Switzerland, her German salary will be comparatively low. I would be able to support both of us, but I'm not sure if that will satisfy potential legal requirements as we're not married.

Edit: I've found the guidelines for ["Residing in Switzerland without gainful activity"](https://www.sem.admin.ch/sem/en/home/themen/fza_schweiz-eu-efta/eu-efta_buerger_schweiz/factsheets.html). Is this related to our situation? I'm not sure whether Germany or Switzerland would tax my girlfriends income. If it's the latter, from a Swiss point-of-view, my girlfriend might as well unemployed.

Comment: Have you contacted the Einwohnerkontrolle in Zürich yet? It may be possible to live in Switzerland and work in Germany, provided your income is high enough. And you will of course have to pay taxes and social security etc. in Switzerland. And your German employer may have to cooperate as well.

Comment: @KristvanBesien no, I haven't. But it'll get in touch and ask them. I'll post their response once I get one.

Comment: if you don't mind me asking, does she have to taxed in Switzerland as well as in Germany? Did you reach to them by email?

Answer (score 1):

I reached out to the Migrationsamt of Zurich, and they replied that my girlfriend would be allowed to reside in Zurich if she can prove to have a health insurance and enough money not to rely on social security.

They referred to (Art. 24 Abs. 2 Anhang I FZA) and (Art. 16 Abs. 1 VFP).